# Help with REST $filter $select option

Tags: rest

I have a REST call that I'm running to retrieve data on a list and filtering on a lookup field.

This works fine and gives results as expected.

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TitleOfList')/items?$filter=Title_x0020_of_x0020_Request eq 31
```

When I try to only select the values I need it returns empty

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TitleOfList')/items?$filter=Title_x0020_of_x0020_Request eq 31&$select=Title,ID
```

I've used this query on other lists, but I've only made filters by ID, not the lookup field. Is there anything special I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the results for a while I noticed

> Title_x0020_of_x0020_Request

was returning as

> Title_x0020_of_x0020_RequestId

Changing the filter to `$filter=Title_x0020_of_x0020_Request/Id` solved my issue.

Comment: You might want to try using the $expand operator when querying against lookup data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx